# YAML ignore decimal values like `X.0`

Tags: r, yaml

On loading a yaml file with values such as 25.0, the `.0` is ignored and what I get is 25. Is it possible to force yaml to consider the value as it is without manipulating the data? I have tried enclosing the values in single/double quotes, but that does not work.

[Edit]: I am using the `yaml` parser package for R programming language. The data type returned is `double`. If I set the value to 25.2, I get back the same value. How can I force YAML/R to read the the information in YAML as it is.

Comment: Which language parser are you using? What's the datatype the parser returns? Depending on the language (e.g. JavaScript) and datatype it might be a language "feature".

Comment: @TorstenWalter: Added information above

Comment: Technically the parser is not ignoring the `.0` value. It most likely is a language feature to trim floats when there is no meaningful value after the decimal point. I have no idea about R so I can't answer that with 100% certainty though.

Comment: Yes. I did not word it properly.

Comment: Didn't want to sound like a smart ass ;) Maybe as long as it is a number you can't really do anything about it and have to add the zeros afte the decimal point when you convert to String. Again, I don't know R, but JavaScript has `Number(1.0).toFixed(2)` which returns a string `1.00`.

Comment: Haha . There is nothing smart ass-ish about it. Infact, I sounded dumb :-P. Right now, I am appending `.0`. My main intention of this post was to try finding out if we can force yaml to read data as it is.

Comment: So you want this value to be a YAML "string" and an R "character" value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the parser recognises that these are floating point numbers and in R there is no difference between 25.0 and 25. Try this for example:

`identical(25.0, 25)`

25.0 and 25 are just two different representations of the same floating point number. If you want to retain the form in which the data is supplied you will have to read them in as strings (which you can later convert to numeric if you need to perform calculations). You can do this with a handler:

`yaml.load("25.0", handlers=list("float#fix"=function(x) as.character(x)))`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help: http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/help/06/05/28016.html

Its suggested to change the settings for digits and possibly round the numbers too to avoid too many decimal places.

> options(digits=2)
>
> format(rounf(x, 2), nsmall = 2)